# Git merge --abort : error: Untracked working tree file 'src/components/footer.jsx' would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, merge, branch, conflict, abort

I just merged a branch into another.
When I tried to abort, I got this error message :

> error: Untracked working tree file 'src/components/footer.jsx' would be overwritten by merge.
>
> fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.

I did not fixed any conflict yet, how come I can't just go back with git merge --abort ?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: I've never seen that particular thing happen with `git merge --abort`, but the error message itself is pretty much self-explanatory: there's an untracked file, and the action you asked for would cause Git to overwrite it, destroying whatever precious data it might have. Inspect the file, decide for yourself whether its data are precious, and if so, save them somewhere—e.g., move the file itself out of the Git repository entirely—or if not, just remove the file.

Comment: Thanks @torek for your help. I just got rid of the branch, which was an old copy of a branch made for test purposes, and had to many conflicts with the branch I was trying to merge, not interesting to resolve.